# JQuery animation and effects apply for several elements with $.when() and then()

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-animate, code-complexity

I have html element like this,

```
<div class="row h-100 p-3 justify-content-center align-items-center m-0">
        <h1 class="col-12 text-center position-absolute welcome-line-1 d-none-edited" id="welcome-line-1">TEXT 01</h1>
        <h3 class="col-12 text-center position-absolute welcome-line-2 d-none-edited" id="welcome-line-2">TEXT 02</h3>
        <h2 class="col-12 text-center position-absolute welcome-line-3 d-none-edited" id="welcome-line-3">TEXT 03</h2>
    </div>
```

and I want to animate these text elements using jQuery.This is my jquery code for one element.

```
var line_1_anim = function(){
            return $('#welcome-line-1')
                .css('opacity', 0)
                .slideDown('slow')
                .animate(
                    { opacity: 1 },
                    { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }
                )
                .delay(1000)
                .slideUp('slow');
        }
```

and lets assume I have three elements and i use this kind of approach to animate each element one by one using $.when() and then()

```
$.when(line_1_anim())
   .then(line_2_anim)
```

I am trying to reduce the code complexity and achieve this. Already my functions work, but I want to do more. Because if I want to add 10 more elements I have to repeat same code 10 times. So I write something like this.

```
var line_animation = function(selector,delay){
            return selector
                .css('opacity', 0)
                .slideDown('slow')
                .animate(
                    { opacity: 1 },
                    { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }
                )
                .delay(delay)
                .slideUp('slow');
        }

        $.when(line_animation(line_1,1000))
        .then(line_animation(line_2,2000))
        .then(line_animation(line_3,3000));
```

I simply planned to change selector and delay and run the same method several time. But this doesn't work like I want. All the functions work at once and not, one after the other.

Any idea what is the wrong with my approach and how can I achieve this.

Hope I have explained my question and everything is clear.

Comment: `functionName()` is a function invocation.  You are executing the line_animation immediately three times when the script runs.  This is similar to how if you do `setTimeout(line_animation(), 1000);` the function will execute immediately, because that is what you are doing, and the fix would be to change it to `setTimeout(line_animation, 1000)` or `setTimeout(function(){ line_animation() }, 1000);`.  The same issue applies to your when/then/then chain

Comment: Taking notice of how you have your first example of a when/then it looks like you understand this concept, so I'm assuming this was just an oversite?

Comment: Thanks @Taplar, Yes I am just trying do something more. thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [jQuery promise example](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) you can rewrite all like (i.e.: line_animation  should return a promise and not a jQuery object):

```js
var line_animation = function (selector, delay) {
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    selector.css('opacity', 0)
            .slideDown('slow')
            .animate({opacity: 1}, {queue: false, duration: 'slow'})
            .delay(delay)
            .slideUp('slow', function () {
                dfd.resolve("hurray");
            });
    return dfd.promise();  // return a promise....
}

$.when(line_animation($('#welcome-line-1'), 1000)).then(function () {
    line_animation($('#welcome-line-2'), 2000).then(function () {
        line_animation($('#welcome-line-3'), 3000);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="row h-100 p-3 justify-content-center align-items-center m-0">
    <h1 class="col-12 text-center position-absolute welcome-line-1 d-none-edited" id="welcome-line-1">TEXT 01</h1>

    <h3 class="col-12 text-center position-absolute welcome-line-2 d-none-edited" id="welcome-line-2">TEXT 02</h3>

    <h2 class="col-12 text-center position-absolute welcome-line-3 d-none-edited" id="welcome-line-3">TEXT 03</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @gaetanoM, This works charm. Once I tried to apply promise to this but I failed. But you did it correctly and I learn from you.  Thanks again.